# Page captions (of tab control) not shown in print preview

Tags: ms-access, printing, tabs, ms-access-2010, print-preview

I'm using MS Access 2010 and have created a simple form with a 2-page tab control. On each page is a single label.

In Design View, the form looks like this...

[image: Simple form - Design View]

In Form View, the tab control and appropriate label are shown as expected...

[image: Simple form - Form View]

However, when I print preview what is shown in the Form View, the label on the active page is shown but the page caption and tab control border are missing...

[image: Simple form - Print Preview]

I've tried tweaking virtually every property of the tab control and pages to no avail. As you can see from the first image above, the `Display When` property is set to `Always`. Even setting it to `Print Only` makes no difference to what is shown in the print preview.

How do I ensure the page caption and tab control border are shown when printing the form?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on a fairly old article but I think it is still valid.  The answer is because Microsoft doesn't want them too.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbview/167064

That states that if you want to print a tab control you need to use an ActiveX one.

Reading online seems to say "Forms aren't for printing, reports are, if you want to print something make a report". Obviously this last point is a little subjective.

Comment: Many thanks for digging up that old article - I did a fair bit of searching prior to posting and couldn't find any such reference. Interestingly, the article mentions that the tabs are invisible even when the Tab Control is on a report which seems strange - although I've not tried this. In all likelihood, I doubt I will replace the Tab Control on my form with a TabStrip control as it seems like quite a clunky implementation and creates a dependency I'd rather not introduce. Instead, I'll probably use a label with the "Display When" property set to "Print Only" in lieu of the tab page caption.

Comment: No problem at all, I have many years of call center experience which was 95% google searching haha.